# How open the file of cookies in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, cookies

Where do I find `cookies` files in `Ubuntu` ( `MOZILLA FIREFOX` ) 
And how to open these `files` ?
Where can I find a `cookie` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1627046
There you will find location for cookies.

http://sqlitebrowser.org
Here you can find how to access an sqlite database.

Comment: Where can I find a cookie file?

Comment: cookies are in your /home directory. just cd .mozilla/firefox/ then there has to be a weird directory name. mine is 68oyiz3n.default And in this directory there is the cookies.sqlite file. this is what you are looking for.

Comment: existe : Crash Reports  czzv3lm3.default  profiles.ini